# WPF SplitButton?

Tags: wpf, button, split-button

I've just spent a very frustrating afternoon trawling Google looking for a commercial-grade WPF `SplitButton` control that will work in a `ToolBar`. A `SplitButton` is one where you can click on the main part of the `Button` to take a default action, or click on a little triangle on the right to get a drop-down menu of alternate actions).

I found several on the web (including the one on CodeProject, and including the two on CodePlex). None of them work properly in a `ToolBar`--they either don't appear at all, or they don't have toolbar button styling. I even looked at some commercial offerings, like ActiPro's pop-up button (in their SharedLibrary DLL). Same problems.

And yes, I've seen all the posts about how easy it is to create one. It's very easy to create a bad one, but not so easy to create one that looks and works like the `SplitButton`s in Outlook or Visual Studio, where the drop-down menu doesn't disappear if you release the mouse button.

So, here's my question: Are there any commercial-grade `SplitButton`s out there, either open-source or commercial, that work in toolbars? I'm not looking for a control that is part of a $1,500 annual subscription to somebody's controls library, but if there is a reasonably-priced `SplitButton`, I'd sure like to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only true "commercial-grade" split button that I know of is the one by [Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/tools/ribbon-splitbuttons), which is included as part of their ribbon controls (although it works outside of the ribbon as well).

That being said, I remember [this implementation](http://shevaspace.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!FD9A0F1F8DD06954!453.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=446231091) as being fairly usable and complete, if you're looking for something free.

Comment: Yeah, I came across Zhou Yong's implementation in my initial search. Unfortunately, the source code link is broken.

Comment: Update: I looked again at Zhou Yong's blog and fond a comment where someone said they found the source code on Channel9. Found it here: http://channel9.msdn.com/playground/Sandbox/244830-SplitButton/

Comment: Note that Syncfusion now has two SplitButtons: The *SplitButton*, which is part of their Ribbon controls, also works well in ToolBars. The *SplitButtonAdv*, in contrast, draws a "button border" around itself, which means it doesn't fit in visually in a ToolBar.

Comment: @Daniel: This is (one of many things) I don't particularly like about Syncfusion's WPF offerings - then again, they're probably my lease favorite WPF vendor overall....  In the last two years, most WPF toolkit vendors now include this functionality, in a single, cleaner package.

Comment: Syncfusion is now free ... sort of, they have a "Community" license so if you'er a solo or a small shop then look it up.

Comment: Here's the license CAD was mentioning: https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense (since I had trouble finding it)

Answer (score 6):

Another good free implementation that seem to have it all:

http://huydinhpham.blogspot.com/2008/09/wpf-drop-down-and-split-button.html

- The split button can be used in the toolbar and has a proper toolbar style. It can also be restyled if you want.
- Dropdown menu is exposed via its own property - i.e splitbutton can have it's own context menu separate from the dropdown one (even though it seems illogical it can be useful in some cases - like toolbar context menu that pops up when you right click on a button placed in the toolbar).
- The dropdown menu is standard ContextMenu - i.e. content can be databound, menu items restyled etc.
- Both the main and the dropdown parts of the split button have command properties associated with them.

Comment: Thanks for the link--I upvoted your response

Comment: Seems to be designed for XP style (Luna) only, does not adapt to Aero theme.

Answer (score 5):

The [Extended WPF Toolkit Community Edition](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SplitButton&referringTitle=Home) (which is free) has a nice `SplitButton` (and it has a `DropDownButton` as well)

[image: SplitButton screen capture]

```
<xctk:SplitButton Content="Click Me">
    <xctk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
        <xctk:ColorCanvas />
    </xctk:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
 </xctk:SplitButton>
```

Comment: Before anyone bothers trying it: This implementation is not very useful because it only has support for adding "any" content in the dropdown area. An actual menu (like 99% of all split buttons would how) that looks like one is not possible :(

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what exactly you are looking for in a split button, but this video on how to create one is pretty complete and makes a splitbutton that is just about perfect.

http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=3929

I know you didn't want a tutorial, but I've used this before and you couldn't tell the difference between it and the ones in outlook.

Comment: That link doesn't work any more. Lee Brimelow seems to have vanished, which is a shame. I saw the video referenced several times when I was searching for a button, and apparently the tutorial is quite good. If you come across a working link, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Ah bummer you are right.  What a shame - it was a good presentation.

Comment: I've contacted him about the video.  He appears to work for Adobe now... hopefully he'll be willing to share those videos again.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up Anderson--much appreciated. I upvoted your response.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pretty good split button implementation for WPF and Silverlight over Delay's blog:

[Banana SplitButton (A WPF-specific fix for SplitButton and some code analysis improvements for the Silverlight version, too)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/07/06/banana-splitbutton-a-wpf-specific-fix-for-splitbutton-and-some-code-analysis-improvements-for-the-silverlight-version-too.aspx)

Comment: This is the one I'm currently using. There are a few problems with this implementation though but compared to the others out there I think it is the nicest looking and most simplistic.

Comment: Yeah, the one problem I've currently seen is that it directly references to the Aero theme assemblies, which makes it have an inconsistent look on classic/non-Aero themes.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is called a DropDownButton.
There is a boolean property on MenuItem "StaysOpenOnClick" which could solve your problem.

Comment: Why -1? was something wrong I said?

Comment: I didn't put in the downvote, but I think you may have misunderstood the question. A DropDown Button drops its menu no matter where it is clicked. A SplitButton has two regions; a main region and a drop-down region. If you click on the main region, the button takes a default action. If you click on the drop-down region, it drops its menu. If you look at the 'New Project' button on the VS 2008 Main toolbar, you will see an example of a SplitButton.

Comment: David, yes but you can put a normal button next to another dropdown button that only has a down arrow icon in it to achieve the same effect

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same and just rolled my own (you will need to style to your liking (to match the ToolBar) and you could refactor it / convert it into a custom control ... etc.)

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Split" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Command="{Binding MainCommand}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource MainCommandImage}"/>
            <TextBlock>MainCommand</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
    <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5"/>
    <CheckBox Width="16" IsThreeState="False">
        <Grid>
            <Path Fill="Black" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}"
                  Stretch="Uniform" Height="6" Width="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Popup x:Name="popupOptions" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Fade" StaysOpen="False" 
                   Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Split}" HorizontalOffset="-3"
                   IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CheckBox}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsChecked}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource SubCommandImage1}"/>
                        <TextBlock>SubCommand1</TextBlock>
                     </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource SubCommandImage2}"/>
                        <TextBlock>SubCommand2</TextBlock>
                     </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the WPF Toolkit split button to show a context menu is reasonably straight forward. Add a context menu in your window resources. On the window load - bind the context menu to the split button and then use the context menu as you would do normally.

It really needs to be added in the WPF Toolkit as the majority use case for this button is to replicate the old WinForm Splitt button.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="SplitButtonTesting.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu" IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}">
        <MenuItem Header="One" />
        <MenuItem Header="Two" />
        <MenuItem Header="More...">
            <MenuItem Header="One" />
            <MenuItem Header="Two" />
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>

    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="ApplicationMenu">

        <xctk:SplitButton x:Name="SplitButton" Content="Main Button" DropDownContent="{x:Null}" />

    </Menu>
    <Border />

</DockPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace SplitButtonTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetupSplitButton();
        }

        public void SetupSplitButton()
       {
           var menu = this.Resources["contextMenu"] as ContextMenu;

           menu.PlacementTarget = SplitButton;

            menu.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
            menu.DataContext = SplitButton;
        }
    }
}
```