# Toolbar Button with Context Menu? Like New Project Button in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, silverlight, contextmenu, toolbar

I need a toolbar button similiar to the "New Project" button in the standard Visual Studio toolbar.  When clicked, it pops up a dialog.  However, it also has a small little down-arrow next to the icon graphic that, when clicked, expands a context menu with more options.

Is there a standard control available with this functionality?

Comment: Have you tried using http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/03/introducing-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf.aspx They have a RibbonSplitButton, that may be possible to port into a Toolbar, not sure.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe Microsoft uses this kind of control all over the place, but they don't have anything similiar available for developers to use.  Not fair!  It's a great control from a usability perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's built in functionality for a SplitButton in WPF currently. Here's another thread that may help you out though:

[WPF SplitButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413536/wpf-splitbutton)

You could combine a couple of controls together to make one fairly quickly. Might as well make a new UserContol out of it that can be re-used throughout your app as well.

Also, a quick search on WPF SplitButton will return a lot of examples on how to make one or you could get one off of CodeProject or CodePlex (though I'm not sure if they'll come with a image property automatically).