# How do I create a dropdown button which shows more button option

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Visual representation of what I want to create 
[image]

I want to create something that functions similar to the `ComboBox` but there are a few issues with the `ComboBox` that I can't seem to fix.
For instance, I want a static text at the top and then have some buttons fall down.

Not sure where to start, I've been thinking about styling a `ComboBox` but is this the best way to approach this?

What's the proper way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Seems like you want what is commonly called a splitbutton. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413536/wpf-splitbutton I use a commercial library that has a good one, Actipro.

Comment: You could combine a ToggleButton and a Popup (for the flyout). ComboBox may have unwanted features like item selection. Styling a Menu seems to be the better choice.

Comment: I agree I'd use a ContextMenu. It's fairly straightforward to trigger a menu open on left-click rather than right-click. There are many Q&As about this here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve somethign very simitlar by just using a Menu and MenuItem.
Of cause you would have to style it to match your linking, but the functionality wand would be there already:

```
<Menu>                       
                    <MenuItem Header="Hello, Wendy">
                        <MenuItem Header="Settings">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="HotPink" Data="M12,15.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 8.5,12A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 12,8.5A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 15.5,12A3.5,3.5 0 0,1 12,15.5M19.43,12.97C19.47,12.65 19.5,12.33 19.5,12C19.5,11.67 19.47,11.34 19.43,11L21.54,9.37C21.73,9.22 21.78,8.95 21.66,8.73L19.66,5.27C19.54,5.05 19.27,4.96 19.05,5.05L16.56,6.05C16.04,5.66 15.5,5.32 14.87,5.07L14.5,2.42C14.46,2.18 14.25,2 14,2H10C9.75,2 9.54,2.18 9.5,2.42L9.13,5.07C8.5,5.32 7.96,5.66 7.44,6.05L4.95,5.05C4.73,4.96 4.46,5.05 4.34,5.27L2.34,8.73C2.21,8.95 2.27,9.22 2.46,9.37L4.57,11C4.53,11.34 4.5,11.67 4.5,12C4.5,12.33 4.53,12.65 4.57,12.97L2.46,14.63C2.27,14.78 2.21,15.05 2.34,15.27L4.34,18.73C4.46,18.95 4.73,19.03 4.95,18.95L7.44,17.94C7.96,18.34 8.5,18.68 9.13,18.93L9.5,21.58C9.54,21.82 9.75,22 10,22H14C14.25,22 14.46,21.82 14.5,21.58L14.87,18.93C15.5,18.67 16.04,18.34 16.56,17.94L19.05,18.95C19.27,19.03 19.54,18.95 19.66,18.73L21.66,15.27C21.78,15.05 21.73,14.78 21.54,14.63L19.43,12.97Z"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Logout">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="HotPink" Data="M16,17V14H9V10H16V7L21,12L16,17M14,2A2,2 0 0,1 16,4V6H14V4H5V20H14V18H16V20A2,2 0 0,1 14,22H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,20V4A2,2 0 0,1 5,2H14Z"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>

                    </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
```

[image]